# How to map a function over a part of a nested data structure?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I want to map a function of type `Float -> Float` over a part of a data structure which looks like this.

```
VDstruct { _onBuild = Just True                                                                                          
         , _imageName = Just "arc.png"                                                                                        
         , _category = Just "All"                                                                                         
         , _mmo = Just 210                                                                                                     
         , _structTypes = Just                                                                                                  
               ( Mage                                                                                                           
                   { _ict = Nothing                                                                                            
                   , _create = Just 1.24                                                                                          
                   , _sh = Nothing                                                                                                                                                                                     
                   }    
         }
```

I want to apply that function to `_ict`, `_create` and to `_sh`.

I know how to do that for each one of those.
I'm using Lenses to help me out with that.
The result has `_create = Just 5.4` which is exactly what I expect from `plusXPercent` function.
This is what I'm using right now.

```
setSer x = x & (structTypes . _Just . create) %~ fmap plusXPercent
```

What I want to do is instead of naming every `_ict`, `_sh`, etc. I want a way to 'map' that function over the entirety of `Mage` structure.

How should I go about doing that?

Edit: `_ict`, `_create` and `_sh` have type `Maybe Float`

and `Mage` is defined like this

```
data Mage = Mage { _ict :: Maybe Float
                 , _create :: Maybe Float
                 , _sh :: Maybe Float
                 } deriving Show
```

Comment: Oh, so `_ict, _sh :: Maybe Float` (this should be in the Q), and you want to apply `plusXPercent` on all of them? No way unless you generate that from TH as well. OTOH, generating that from TH isn't that hard, assuming you already know how to write lens generators using TH, which now that I think about it sounds reasonably obscure to not assume that everyone can do that. [Alternatives are all bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807619/systematically-applying-a-function-to-all-fields-of-a-haskell-record), though...

Comment: I felt bad about leaving you with that, so going further: the type of your record declaration is gonna be [`Dec` constructed with `DataD`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.14.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Dec). You'll be interested in the `Con` part, which [has the RecC constructor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.14.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Con). From there it's just a list of tuples of `(Name, Bang, Type)`, of which you need the `Name` if you assume they're all `Maybe Float`. Armed with that list, you can generate a traversal lens.

Comment: I'm assuming `Mage` is not defined with something like `data Mage a = Mage { _ict :: Maybe a, ...}`?

Comment: Perhaps define a `MonoFunctor` instance for `Mage`?

Comment: @chepner (To your first comment) No, but that'd been textbook case for an Applicative instance. I've updated the question with it's actual definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `mono-traversable` package, you can define a `MonoFunctor` instance for `Mage`.

```
type instance Element Mage = Maybe Float

instance MonoFunctor Mage where
    omap f (Mage x y z) = Mage (f x) (f y) (f z)
```

Then you can use `omap` to apply (e.g.) `fmap (+1)` to every field
of `Mage`.

```
 omap (fmap (+1)) (Mage { _ict = Nothing                                   
                        , _create = Just 1.24                                                                                          
                        , _sh = Nothing
                        })
   == Mage { _ict = Nothing, _create = Just 2.24, _sh = Nothing }
```

Then, I think, you would write (sorry, just guessing, lenses aren't my strong suit):

```
--setSer x = x & (structTypes . _Just . create) %~ fmap plusXPercent

setSer x = x & (structTypes . _Just) %~ (omap (fmap plusXPercent))
```

However, `MonoFunctor` may be overkill; you can accomplish the same thing with the `Applicative` instance for functions.

```
foo :: (Maybe Float -> Maybe Float) -> Mage -> Mage
foo f = Mage <$> f . _ict <*> f . _create <*> f . _sh
```

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong but I'm getting error - `Couldn't match expected type 'Element Mage' with actual type 'Maybe Float'`

Comment: I omitted the type instance for `Element`, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can always write Traversals by hand, and that's what this calls for. Lens has a class that would apply here, [`Each`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/src/Control.Lens.Each.html#Each).

```
instance (a ~ Float, b ~ Float) => Each Mage Mage a b where
    each f (Mage i c s) = Mage <$> traverse f i <*> traverse f c <*> traverse f s
```

You could also write that Traversal without the class, but you might as well re-use the name when it's appropriate.